# How to separate data from one row into two rows in R?

Tags: r, split

For rows that have the value "Separate" in the column called "Submit.and.module", I would like to insert a row directly above it and move data from some of the columns to that new row.

Specifically, I would like to move the data in columns called "Submit.help" and "Strategy" to the new row above.

Right now my data look like this:

[image: data1]

I would like the data to look like this:

[image: data2]

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected output in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please add why you want to do that (perhaps there is a better way to achieve what you need). THX.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do it in dput format. My actual dataset is much more complicated so I created a sample in Excel. The reason I want to do this is because this is chronological log data that captures a user's actions in a tutoring system. There is a flaw in the logs and what should have been captured in two lines is regularly combined into one. I need them separated out because the Submit.help action actually happens before Which.mod

Comment: Steps: Reduce your Excel data to a minimal example. save the sheet as CSV file, use `xread.csv` or `read.csv2` in R to read the file into a variable the "dump" the content of the variable into a text format on the R console via `dput(variable_name)` you can post this output here...

Comment: If you have the data in excel and you are using Rstudio you might want to have a look at library([datapasta](https://github.com/MilesMcBain/datapasta)) to create a `data.frame` from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought I'd join the party with another solution.

**Data**

```
data <- data.frame(Which.mod         = c("TMH", "TMH-C", "TMH", "FC", "FC"),
                   Mod.time          = c(1.43, 2.31, 0.67, 2.35, 8.22),
                   Submit.help       = c(NA, "Help", NA, NA, "Submit"),
                   Strategy          = c(NA, "Ratio", NA, NA, "Count"),
                   Submit.and.module = c(NA, "Separate", NA, NA, "Separate"))
```

**Base R**

Step 1: Make an ID column and a new data frame that is a subset of the rows to be separated.

```
data$id <- 1:nrow(data)
data1 <- subset(data, !is.na(Submit.and.module))
```

Step 2: set appropriate columns to NA and bind the data frames

```
data[, c("Submit.help", "Strategy")] <- NA
data1[, c("Which.mod", "Mod.time", "Submit.and.module")] <- NA
```

Step 3: bind the data frames and order.

```
final <- rbind(data1, data)
final.ordered <- df1[order(df1$id), ]

#    Which.mod Mod.time Submit.help Strategy Submit.and.module id
# 1        TMH     1.43        <NA>     <NA>              <NA>  1
# 2       <NA>       NA        Help    Ratio              <NA>  2
# 21     TMH-C     2.31        <NA>     <NA>          Separate  2
# 3        TMH     0.67        <NA>     <NA>              <NA>  3
# 4         FC     2.35        <NA>     <NA>              <NA>  4
# 5       <NA>       NA      Submit    Count              <NA>  5
# 51        FC     8.22        <NA>     <NA>          Separate  5
```

**Tidyverse**

Nice and easy
 to follow. Same steps as above, but chained as much as possible.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat1 <- data %>% mutate(id = 1:n(), Submit.help = NA, Strategy = NA)
dat2 <- data %>% mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
                 filter(!is.na(Submit.and.module)) %>%
                 mutate(Which.mod = NA, Mod.time = NA, Submit.and.module = NA)
final <- rbind(dat2, dat1) %>% arrange(id)
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice and simple. So when you are creating dat2, the mutate is done before the filtering. I didn't realize you could combine functions like that.

Comment: This is the best party, I've been to (c)

Comment: @HelenaConnolly Yes, the beauty of `tidyverse` is that using pipes makes the code easier to read and also cuts out intermediate variables.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to cut the columns to be duplicated into a separate data table, add it to the original data (at the end) and sort the rows into the right order by using a helper column named "sort":

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(Which.mod         = c("TMH", "TMH-C", "TMH", "FC", "FC"),
                   Mod.time          = c(1.43, 2.31, 0.67, 2.35, 8.22),
                   Submit.help       = c(NA, "Help", NA, NA, "Submit"),
                   Strategy          = c(NA, "Ratio", NA, NA, "Count"),
                   Submit.and.module = c(NA, "Separate", NA, NA, "Separate"))


data[, sort := (1:.N) * 10]  # add a row sorting value with a gap to fill in inserted rows

# cut columns to be duplicated and "insert" at the end    
res <- rbind(data,
             data[Submit.and.module == "Separate", .(sort, Submit.help, Strategy)] [, sort := sort - 1],
             use.names = TRUE,
             fill = TRUE)

# Purge content of moved columns (credits go to @ismiregal - I forgot this initially)
res[Submit.and.module %in% "Separate", c("Submit.help", "Strategy") := NA]

# sort the result accordingly
res <- res[order(sort),]
```

Result:

```
res

   Which.mod Mod.time Submit.help Strategy Submit.and.module sort
1:       TMH     1.43        <NA>     <NA>              <NA>   10
2:      <NA>       NA        Help    Ratio              <NA>   19
3:     TMH-C     2.31        <NA>     <NA>          Separate   20
4:       TMH     0.67        <NA>     <NA>              <NA>   30
5:        FC     2.35        <NA>     <NA>              <NA>   40
6:      <NA>       NA      Submit    Count              <NA>   49
7:        FC     8.22        <NA>     <NA>          Separate   50
```

Answer (score 1):

Code is ugly, but if you need I'll try to explain what it does (if I'll remember it at the morning). For sure there is another, elegant way to do that. But just to celebrate the diversity...

#### Your example data set:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Wich.mod = c("TMH", "TMH-C", "TMH", "FC", "FC"),
  Mod.time = c(1.43, 2.31, 0.67, 2.35, 8.22),
  Submit.help = c(NA, "Help", NA, NA, "Submit"),
  Strategy = c(NA, "Ratio", NA, NA, "Count"),
  Submit.and.module = c(NA, "Separate", NA, NA, "Separate"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

#### Transfromations:

```
## create new data.frame, filled with NA. The same cols, but extra N("Separate") rows

newdata <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow(dat), ncol(dat) + sum(grepl("Separate", dat[, 5]))))

## insert data from dat, leaving empty spaces before "Separate"

newdata[1:nrow(dat) + cumsum(grepl("Separate", dat[, 5])), ] <- dat[1:nrow(dat),]

## give newdata column names from old data

colnames(newdata) <- colnames(dat)

## move Submit.help and Strategy related to "Separate" a row up

newdata[
  which(newdata[, 5] == "Separate") - 1, 3:4
  ] <- newdata[which(newdata[, 5] == "Separate"), 3:4]

## for variables above, replace old values related to "Separate" with NA

newdata[which(newdata[, 5] == "Separate"), 3:4] <- NA
```

#### Output:

```
#  Wich.mod Mod.time Submit.help Strategy Submit.and.module
# 1 TMH          1.43 NA          NA       NA               
# 2 NA           NA   Help        Ratio    NA               
# 3 TMH-C        2.31 NA          NA       Separate         
# 4 TMH          0.67 NA          NA       NA               
# 5 FC           2.35 NA          NA       NA               
# 6 NA           NA  Submit       Count    NA               
# 7 FC           8.22 NA          NA       Separate
```

Comment: Crazy code, but it works :-) Just saw that my answer ignores the filter on the last col... I will update my alternative which is based on a `data.table`

Comment: Yes, that's true...the weird thing - I feel that I don't understand it already :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another data.table solution (it seems I was too slow):

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
               Index = seq(5),
           Which.mod = c("TMH", "TMH-C", "TMH", "FC", "FC"),
            Mod.time = c(1.43, 2.31, 0.67, 2.35, 8.22),
         Submit.help = c(NA, "Help", NA, NA, "Submit"),
            Strategy = c(NA, "Ratio", NA, NA, "Count"),
   Submit.and.module = c(NA, "Separate", NA, NA, "Separate")
)

DT <- rbindlist(list(DT, DT[Submit.and.module %in% "Separate", c("Index", "Submit.help", "Strategy")]), use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
DT[Submit.and.module %in% "Separate", c("Submit.help", "Strategy") := NA]
setorder(DT, Index, Mod.time, na.last=FALSE)
print(DT)
```

[image]

Comment: What I like most is the `setorder` combined with `na.last`. Well done :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution :

```
library(tidyverse)
nms <- names(df1)
df1 %>% 
  rowid_to_column %>%
  gather(,,-rowid) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(tmp = key %in% c("Which.mod","Mod.time","Submit.and.module")) %>%
  spread(key,value) %>%
  select_at(nms)

#   Which.mod Mod.time Submit.help Strategy Submit.and.module
# 1       TMH     1.43        <NA>     <NA>              <NA>
# 2      <NA>     <NA>        Help    Ratio              <NA>
# 3     TMH-C     2.31        <NA>     <NA>          Separate
# 4       TMH     0.67        <NA>     <NA>              <NA>
# 5        FC     2.35        <NA>     <NA>              <NA>
# 6      <NA>     <NA>      Submit    Count              <NA>
# 7        FC     8.22        <NA>     <NA>          Separate
```

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Which.mod = c("TMH", "TMH-C", "TMH", "FC", "FC"),
  Mod.time = c(1.43, 2.31, 0.67, 2.35, 8.22),
  Submit.help = c(NA, "Help", NA, NA, "Submit"),
  Strategy = c(NA, "Ratio", NA, NA, "Count"),
  Submit.and.module = c(NA, "Separate", NA, NA, "Separate"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```